# Why is my awk script much slower than the head+tail script?

Tags: shell, awk, sed, tail, head

I want to split a huge file (big.txt). by given line numbers. For example, if the give numbers are `10 15 30`, I will get 4 files: `1-10`, `11-15`, `16-30`, and `30 - EOF` of the big.txt.

Solving the problem is not a challenge for me, I wrote 3 different solutions. However, I cannot explain the performance. Why the awk script is the slowest. (**GNU Awk**)

For the big.txt, I just did `seq 1.5billion > big.txt (~15Gb)`

### first, the head and tail:

```
INPUT_FILE="big.txt"  # The input file
LINE_NUMBERS=( 400000 700000 1200000 ) # Given line numbers
START=0                 # The offset to calculate lines
IDX=1                   # The index used in the name of generated files: file1, file2 ...

for i in "${LINE_NUMBERS[@]}"
do
    # Extract the lines
    head -n $i "$INPUT_FILE" | tail -n +$START > "file$IDX.txt"
    #
    (( IDX++ ))
    START=$(( i+1 ))
done

# Extract the last given line - last line in the file
tail -n +$START "$INPUT_FILE" > "file$IDX.txt"
```

### The 2nd: sed:

```
INPUT_FILE="big.txt"  # The input file
LINE_NUMBERS=( 400000 700000 1200000 ) # Given line numbers
START=1                 # The offset to calculate lines
IDX=1                   # The index used in the name of generated files: file1, file2 ...

for i in "${LINE_NUMBERS[@]}"
do
    T=$(( i+1 ))
    # Extract the lines using sed command
    sed -n -e " $START, $i p" -e "$T q" "$INPUT_FILE" > "file$IDX.txt"
    (( IDX++ ))
    START=$T
done

# Extract the last given line - last line in the file
sed -n "$START, $ p" "$INPUT_FILE" > "file$IDX.txt"
```

### the last, awk

```
awk -v nums="400000 700000 1200000" 'BEGIN{c=split(nums,a)} {
    for(i=1; i<=c; i++){
        if( NR<=a[i] ){
            print > "file" i ".txt"
            next
        }
    }
    print > "file" c+1 ".txt"
}' big.txt
```

From my testing (using `time` command), the **head+tail** is the fastest:

```
real 73.48
user 1.42
sys 17.62
```

the **sed** one:

```
real 144.75
user 105.68
sys 15.58
```

the **awk** one:

```
real 234.21
user 187.92
sys 3.98
```

The awk went through the file only once, why it is much slower than the other two? Also, I thought the tail and head would be the slowest solution, how come it's so fast? I guess it might be something to do with the awk's redirection? (print > file)

Can someone explain it to me? Thank you.

Comment: Heh. When I saw this question, I _assumed_ that it would be asked by someone who didn't know that `tail` could `seek()`; it's rather considerably more interesting than that. :)

Comment: BTW, which specific awk implementation are you using? (gawk, at least, caches and reuses file descriptors for redirections; but for others, it might be worth checking).

Comment: There's a bit of similar discussion on this here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it's gawk. I've updated the question to include the information.

Comment: You know there's a `split` command, right?

Comment: @tripleee yes I know. but can split solve the problem?

Comment: `split` can certainly split into even-sized chunks like your original example. If you mean split into arbitrary piles like in your later examples, I think you need `csplit` for that.

Comment: I don't think I made examples with splitting into even-sized (lines) files. I don't have much experience with csplit. Perhaps it could solve the problem too, but I still want to know why the awk is slower than the head/tail. Thanks. @tripleee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Can `awk` be faster than `head` and `tail` for this?**

No, it will be slower, at least for a reasonable number of chunks for a large input file. Because it will read every line and do some work with it. On the other hand, `head` and `tail` will read massively the newline characters, without doing anything, will seek until they find the line number provided by the argument. Then they don't have again to read line by line and decide what to do, but dump the content, similar to `cat`.

If we increase the number of chunks, if the array of splitting line numbers is getting larger and larger, then we will reach a point where the cost of calling many `head` and `tail` processes will overcome the cost of one `awk` process, and from that point after, `awk` would be faster.

---

**`awk` script improvement**

This `awk` is slow because of that loop! Just think that for the last output file, for every line to print, we run 4 iterations until we print the line. Of course the time complexity still remains linear to the input, but all these checks and assignments have costs that can be observed as input grows. It can be much improved, e.g. like this:

```
> cat tst.awk
BEGIN { 
    a[1]
    a[40000]
    a[70000]
    a[120000]
}

NR in a {
    close(out)
    out = "file" ++i ".txt"
}

{ print > out }
```

Here we test only NR per line, actually we almost only print.

```
awk -f tst.awk big.txt
```

---

**Testing**

Here is some basic testing, I did a file, not huge, 5.2M lines.

```
> wc -l big.txt 
5288558 big.txt
```

Now, with that loop, it really matters **where** you split the file! If you have to write most of the rows into the last chunks, that means more iterations, it is slower

```
> head -1 test.sh
awk -v nums="100000 200000 300000" 'BEGIN{c=split(nums,a)} {
> time sh test.sh

real    0m10.960s
user    0m10.823s
sys     0m0.066s
```

If most rows goes to first file (that means one iteration and next) it becomes faster!

```
> head -1 test.sh
awk -v nums="5000000 5100000 5200000" 'BEGIN{c=split(nums,a)} {
> time sh test.sh

real    0m6.914s
user    0m6.838s
sys     0m0.043s
```

With the above modification it should be fast enough regardless the cut points.

```
> time awk -f tst.awk big.txt 

real    0m4.270s
user    0m4.185s
sys     0m0.048s
```

Comment: Thanks, the explanation in the first paragraph helps. During my testing, I did remove the loop as well, it was indeed faster than the awk cmd with the loop, but I was focusing on the comparison to the head&tail script.

Answer (score 0):

For awk, each line requires a loop, comparisons, and creating the filename.  Maybe awk performs also the hard task of parsing each line.

You may want to try the following experiments

- try mawk (fast implementation of awk) and check if it is much faster.
- remove `print > "file" i ".txt"` see how much time it saves.